# How to use Orion Context Broker to draw a circle on the map viewer

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud, fiware-poi

I want to draw a circle on the map viewer, and I searched the programmer developer guide carefully. My Json file was created like this.

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "entities": [
  {
    "type": "City",
    "isPattern": "true",
    "id": ".*"
  }
  ],
  "restriction": {
    "scopes": [
    {
      "type" : "FIWARE::Location",
      "value" : {
        "circle": {
          "centerLatitude": "43.659590",
          "centerLongitude": "-79.397077",
          "radius": "15000"
        }
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
EOF
```

I'm wondering how to use ngsi source operator and ngsi entity to POI to draw the circle on the map viewer on Fiware? It would be great if someone can provide me some detail about the steps.

Comment: "fiware-poi" tag seems extraneous. This question does not seem to be about FIWARE POI Data Provider Generic Enabler.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible, please open a ticket in the github's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/map-viewer-widget/issues) of the widget :).